Accessibility Service only works when Accessiblity App is in Foreground
I started working with the accessibility Service and tried to make my own Service, that will first for testing reasons just show me, which app was opened.
This works fine as long as it is the Service-App itself. In any other case - so if the app is not in foreground anymore - this service does not work. Did anyone else had this problem that the Accessibility Service only works in the foreground? If this is intendend, then this Service does not really make sense in my eyes?
Heres my AccessibilityService-Class:
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

private static final String TAG = "AccessabilityService_Test";


@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: EventType: " + event.getEventType() + " PackageName: " + event.getPackageName());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String packageName = event.getPackageName() != null ? event.getPackageName().toString() : "null";
    Log.e(TAG, "Detected package: " + packageName);

    PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
    try {
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        CharSequence applicationLabel = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo);
        Log.e(TAG, "App name is: " + applicationLabel);
        Toast.makeText(this, "App name: " + applicationLabel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onInterrupt: something went wrong");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onInterrupt: something went wrong ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected(){
    super. onServiceConnected();
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED |
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED |
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED |
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED;


    // Set the type of feedback your service provides.
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN;

    // Default services are invoked only if no package-specific services are
    // present for the type of AccessibilityEvent generated. This service is
    // app-specific, so the flag isn't necessary. For a general-purpose service,
    // consider setting the DEFAULT flag.

    // info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;

    info.notificationTimeout = 100;

    this.setServiceInfo(info);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Unbind", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

}
I also tried different option using the config (accessibility_service_config.xml):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:packageNames=" com.example.accessabilityservice_test,  com.example.accessabilityservice_test"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.accessibility.ServiceSettingsActivity"
    />

Also, the it is registred as service in the AndroidManifest.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AccessabilityService_Test"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
            android:label="@string/accessibility_service_label"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>

I tried it on an emulator as well as on my phone directly and an older Phone. Also the service is activated in the settings.
(Google Pixel 8, Android Version 15 /  Medium Phone API 35)

Toasts don't work from the background anymore on newer Android versions. I would suggest that you remove those entirely, and try again with just logs.

Oh, also, you have android:packageNames set to only receive events from your app. Perhaps you've misunderstood what that attribute is for?
